# Handling infinite/large values in column for ML classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, missing-data

Computed a column using a formula (formula does't involve any log functions, just a group by with `.sum()`), but as expected this column would result in `infinite/exponential values` like below:

```
-inf
 nan
 inf
-3.000e+32
 7.3297+23 ...etc (similar data)
```

My doubt is how should I handle this column as `I could also not avoid this column for prediction` for a binary classification problem. What are the techniques to use before using this column in model classifier.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your function computing a feature (the column) returns `nan` or `inf` I would be suspicious. Why is this the case?

In general if you have large values like yours, you can try to apply a [log-transformation](http://onlinestatbook.com/2/transformations/log.html) to scale down your values to more useful intervals.